# Combinatorics Path - Graph problem

Tags: graph-theory

A $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cake cube is made of $1 \times 1 \times 1$ little cake cubes.

A rat eats one of the top corner little cubes. After eating any little cube , the rat can go on to eat any adjacent little cube.

Can the rat eat through all cake cubes finishing last with the center cube ?

Comment: Hint: The "obvious" graph is bipartite, has an odd number of vertices, and the corner and the center are in different parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternately colour the cubes black and white so that the rat starts at a white cube. There are $14$ white cubes and $13$ black cubes, so any path through all cubes must end at a white cube. But the centre cube is black by the colouring, so the rat cannnot eat all cubes and end up at the centre.